# How to read first character of a String in C

Tags: java, c, string, loops, char

Given a String `"Hello"` in C, how would a method look that returns the `"H"` in the String.

Then once I've determined how to do that, I'd like to take it a step further and remove the first character from the initial String so that the next time that I read it `"Hello"` becomes `"ello"`, and when I call the read method again it will return the `"e"`?

I know how to do this in other languages, like Java but I'm not as proficient in C so I'm really struggling with this concept.

Here's how I would do this in java.

```
public class Program1 {

private String expression = "-(1+3)*4/6";

public String cut_string(String word)
{

    String temp = word.substring(1, word.length());
    return temp;
}

public char readToken()
{
    if(expression.length() > 1)
    {
        char token = expression.charAt(0);
        expression = cut_string(expression);
        return token;
    }else {
        System.out.print("BROKEN AT READ TOKEN");
        return ' ';
    }

}

public String getExpression()
{
    return expression;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Program1 thing = new Program1();


    System.out.println("The token was: " + thing.readToken()
            + "\n" + "The remaining String is: " 
                + thing.getExpression());

    System.out.println("The token was: " + thing.readToken()
            + "\n" + "The remaining String is: " 
                + thing.getExpression());

    System.out.println("The token was: " + thing.readToken()
            + "\n" + "The remaining String is: " 
                + thing.getExpression());               
}
}
```

The output would be as follows:

```
The token was: -

The remaining String is: (1+3)*4/6

The token was: (

The remaining String is: 1+3)*4/6

The token was: 1

The remaining String is: +3)*4/6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The site works best when you post not just what you want, but what you have already tried. Please post the C code you have so far and what seems to be going wrong.

Comment: I don't really know where to start.. I was hoping this was just a simple solution I was overlooking. At least the portion of it that reads the first char of a string

Answer (score 3):

Coming from Java, you should bear in mind that a "string" in the Java sense is not a native concept to C. In C, you deal explicitly with arrays of characters instead of more abstract data types (unless you build them yourself). Think of them as similar to a `char[]` in Java.

Returning the first character of a string, then, is simply the same as returning the first element of the array that is the string:

```
char first_character(char *string) {
    return(string[0]);
}
```

Changing the program's state, on the other hand, to "remove" the first character of the string, may be completely superfluous in C, depending on how you want to do it. You do, of course, have the option of actually modifying the string by moving all elements back one position, for instance like this:

```
void remove_first_char(char *string) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; string[i] != 0; i++)
        string[i] = string[i + 1];
}
```

(Note, however, that string *literals* are often allocated in read-only memory and cannot be modified.)

But, depending on your context, you could also quite simply modify the pointer that you might be using to just point to the second character instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd *prefer* to avoid global variables (especially in a case like this where it's being modified), but since you seem willing to put up with that, it can be pretty trivial:

```
char expr[] = "-(1+3)*4/6";
char *expression = expr;

char read_token() { 
    return *expression++;
}

int main() { 
    char ch;
    while (ch=read_token()) {
        printf("next token: %c\n", ch);
        printf("The remaining string is: %s\n", expression);
    }
}
```

To encapsulate things a little better, I'd consider something more like this though:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *expression;
} program1;

char read_token(program1 *p) {
    return *p->expression++;
}

int main() {
    program1 p = { "-(1+3)*4/6" };

    char ch;
    while (ch = read_token(&p)) {
        printf("next token: %c\n", ch);
        printf("The remaining string is: %s\n", p.expression);
    }
}
```

At least in my opinion, avoiding globals (among other things) more than makes up for the extra length.

Comment: It seems you slipped a little C++ in there by using `program1` without either the `struct` prefix or a typedef.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Oops. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are stored as an array of characters.

```
char myStr[] = "String";
```

You can access any character by using an array index

```
char myChar = myStr[0];
printf("%c\n", myChar);
```